# Proving certain triangle groups are infinite

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, infinite-groups, combinatorial-group-theory, linear-groups

*[Cross-posted to [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/457762/proving-certain-triangle-groups-are-infinite)]*

Consider the [Von Dyck group](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Von_Dyck_group)

$$ G = \langle x,y\mid x^a=y^b=(xy)^c=1\rangle $$
where $a,b,c\ge3$. Because $G$ is infinite and residually finite, it has an infinite family of finite quotients $\{\overline{G}_n\}$ such that $|\overline{G}_n|\rightarrow\infty$. I'm wondering if there is an expicit such family that can be constructed, giving a direct proof that $G$ is infinite.

Specifically, I'm trying to use Derek Holt's argument (that I copied in [this MO answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/24913/quick-proofs-of-hard-theorems/24940#24940)), which can be used to show $G$ has quotients in $PSL(2,q)$ for infinitely many primes $q$. To summarize: Let $q$ be a prime such that $q-1$ is divisible by $2a$, $2b$, and $2c$. Let $\zeta$ be a primitive element of $\mathbb{F}_q^\ast$, and define $\zeta_t=\zeta^{(p-1)/t}$, so that $|\zeta_t|=t$. Then define the matrixes $X,Y\in SL(2,q)$ as
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
X &= \begin{pmatrix}\zeta_{2a} & 1\\ 0 & \zeta_{2a}^{-1}\end{pmatrix}
\end{aligned}\qquad
\begin{aligned}
Y = \begin{pmatrix}\zeta_{2b} & 0\\\lambda & \zeta_{2b}^{-1}\end{pmatrix}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
where $\lambda = (\zeta_{2c}-\zeta_{2a}\zeta_{2b})+(\zeta_{2c}^{-1}-\zeta_{2a}^{-1}\zeta_{2b}^{-1})$. Then the images $\overline{X},\overline{Y}\in PSL(2,q)$ generate a subgroup $\langle \overline{X},\overline{Y}\rangle$ that is a quotient of $G$.

It seems to me in this case we should actually have $\langle \overline{X},\overline{Y}\rangle=PSL(2,q)$. Is this true, and how hard is the proof? Equivalently (but perhaps easier to show), is it true that $\langle \overline{X},\overline{Y}\rangle$ contains a Sylow $q$-subgroup of $PSL(2,q)$?

**Note**: While I am mostly interested in the specific question of whether $\langle \overline{X},\overline{Y}\rangle=PSL(2,q)$, there are other ways to exhibit an infinite family $\{\overline{G}_n\}$. For example, by reducing to the (perhaps more tractable) case where $a,b,c$ are odd primes or $4$. Or if there are other explicit infinite families -- especially linear -- I'd like to hear about them!

Comment: @DerekHolt who might have particular insight.

Comment: Are you familiar with the proof that shows that this group is infinite via its action on a tessellation of the hyperbolic plane?

Comment: From the known list of subgroups of ${\rm PSL}(2,q)$ for $q$ prime, we can see that the images of $X$ and $Y$ must generate either the whole of ${\rm PSL}(2,q)$, or one of $A_4$, $S_4$ or $A_5$, and these exceptions could only occur when $p,q,r \le 5$. It does not seem likely that we get $A_4$, $S_4$ or $A_5$ for almost all primes $q$ satisfying the condition, but I don't see immediately how to eliminate that possibility.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: Yes I do know that proof. The fact all of these groups (except $(3,3,3)$) ends up in $PSL(2,\mathbb{R})$ -- as well as some computation in GAP -- is what suggested these quotients should be all of $PSL(2,q)$.